# object does not contain definition for 'cells' error

Tags: c#, object, datagridview

I have two datagridview. datagridview1 and datagridview2. when i add a product from datagridview1 to datagridview2 the quantity of the product in datagridview1 is transferred to datagridview2. Now when i remove a product from datagridview2 i need it to transfer the quantity back to datagridview1.

[image]

someone help me before but im getting this error now.
[image]

```
    private int FindRowIndexByID(string id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvPOSproduct.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dgvPOSproduct.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == id)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (var row in dgvPOScart.SelectedRows)
        {
            // Get the row in dgvProducts and the quantity he'll gain back
            var productRow = dgvPOSproduct.Rows[FindRowIndexByID(row.Cells[0].Value)];
            int qtyToAdd = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Value);

            // Add the quantity back
            productRow.Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToInt32(productRow.Cells[5].Value) + qtyToAdd;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop change the `var` with the actual type, which is `DataGridViewRow`.
like this:
`foreach (DataGridViewRowrow in dgvPOScart.SelectedRows){ ....`

Comment: i already  tried that sir but im getting an error. on line 7 of button remove 
((row.Cells[0].Value)];) click it says "cannot convert from object to string"

Comment: `row.Cells[0].Value` returns an object type, But your `FindRowIndexByID` function takes a string, You need to convert it like this: `row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()`

Comment: @FutureDev please don't forget to accept the answer!